# New Google Drive API - how to create shortcut?

Tags: python, google-drive-api, shortcut

I have a folder in Google Drive, and I try to place its shotcuts in several other folders (just organizing my data by tags, e.g. put "Holiday photos" shortcuts in folders "Holidays" and "Photos"). I can easily create a shortcut with:

```
'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut'
```

These shortcuts work great only on Web Application, but I am using desktop "Backup & Sync", where all these shortcuts become files *.gshortcut* and open as web links.

It seems that shortcuts were working in good old days, but on august of last year Google published this:

> https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2020/08/expanding-shortcuts-google-drive.html
>
> When using Drive on the web, the keyboard shortcut Shift+Z on a shared
> file used to place the file in multiple locations. Now, when a single
> file or multiple items are selected, Shift+Z will create a shortcut
> instead. However, if a single folder is selected, Shift-Z will still
> add another location for the folder to ensure continued compatibility
> with offline access via Backup and Sync.

Keyboard shortcut Shift+Z is working great, and it realy creates adequate Windows-friendly shortcuts, but I found no information about this function in Google Drive API Documentation, and moreover, the MIME type of this shortcut is:

```
'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'
```

And I feel this means nothing positive.

> MIME types: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types

I found the official name of this operation:

> Instead of a shortcut, *add the folder to an additional location*. On the Google Drive website, select the folder and press Shift + Z.

But found even less information about it

And, at last, I found the information about Google Drive API update:

> https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/g-suite/simplifying-google-drives-folder-structure-and-sharing-models
>
> A request that creates a new item can no longer specify multiple parents.

So I am 99% sure that this can't be done anymore, but anyway:

Are there any way to create these "Shift+Z" shortcuts with Google Drive API?

Answer (score 3):

### Creating Shortcut using Drive API

When [creating a shortcut to a Drive file](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts?hl=en), you just need to set the following:

- `mimeType` = `application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut`
- `targetId` = file id/folder id that the shortcut will point to.
- `name` = shortcut file name
- `parents` = (Optional) folder id where you want the shortcut to be placed.

**Sample Request Body:**

```
{
  "name": "Test Assignment 3-Shortcut",
  "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.shortcut",
  "parents": [
    "1TrX6KcAJppWCj9GSUjSYn79AqJ1xxxx"
  ],
  "shortcutDetails": {
    "targetId": "0B8xt-68OtkVWfl9OMW5fcjV4RWJsWExRU3B0M0d6SlNacWwyTHZ2cUhoNE1IZ096exxxx"
  }
}
```

**Output**

[image]

---

### Additional Reference:

[Create a shortcut - Python](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/shortcuts?hl=en#create_a_shortcut)

Comment: That works great in web interface, but completely unusable in desktop app. Forgot to say that files shortcuts work fine (in both web and windows), instead of folders shortcuts (that look like web links in windows app) and that's the problem

Comment: I see, anyways did I answer your other concern on how to create shortcut files/folders using Drive API? I can't replicate your issue due to lack of environment available from my end. I could only provide guidelines on how to use the API

Comment: Nah, but anyway that will be useful for strangers looking for how to create shortcuts with Google Drive API